# Vim: paste search register in command line without brackets

Tags: vim

Is there a way in Vim to paste the search register on the command-line, but without the surrounding `\<` brackets `\>`? I often find myself doing a search in a buffer, and then wanting to use the matched pattern as an argument to `grep` (more specifically, [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim)).

Here's what happens if you search for `foo` and then enter `:Ack '<C-r>/`':

```
:Ack '\<foo\>'
```

This will fail  to find anything. What I want instead is:

```
:Ack 'foo'
```

This is of course a simplistic example. Where this would be more valuable is with more complex search results.

I am aware of `<C-r><C-w>` and `<C-r><C-a>` for pasting the word/WORD under the cursor, and these often suffice, but not always.

Comment: `<C-r>/` inserts your search pattern as you typed it. Note that it inserts the *search pattern*, not the match: if you search for `foo\d`, `<C-r>/` will insert `foo\d`, not `foo9`.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. In this case, I was testing things by using `*` to just highlight a word, which is where the surrounding brackets come from. I was also trying earlier with `/pattern`, which I have mapped to `/\v`, and getting the resulting `\v` in the search register, but didn't make the connection. If you want to put your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Also of note for people interested in this, using `g*` instead of `*` will get the search pattern without `\<` brackets `\>` around it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<C-r>/` inserts your search pattern as you typed it: if you did `/foo`, the search register contains `foo`.

Note that `<C-r>/` inserts the search pattern, not the match: if you search for `foo\d`, `<C-r>/` will insert `foo\d`, not `foo9`.

As you found out, `\<` and `\>` are added if you used `*` or `#` in order to limit the search to whole words. Use `g*` and `g#` to *not* search whole words and thus avoid the `\<\>`.

Here is a possibly useful mapping:

```
nnoremap <F6> :Ack '<C-r>=expand("<cword>")<CR>'
```

Comment: Great explanation, makes sense.. I solved this purpose of searching the current highlighted word by using 
> let g:ack_use_cword_for_empty_search = 1
in my vimrc, now if I run :Ack! without any parameters it by defaults search for the word that's in the search buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're doing a purely *literal search*, there's a difference between the search pattern (a regular expression) and the (list of) matches (strings from the buffer).

If you're interested in the latter, my [PatternComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4248) offers insert-mode completion of all matches, and it can also insert the first match of the last search pattern with `<C-R>&`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Is there a GitHub repo or anything that includes the plugin along with all its dependencies, in a pathogen-compatible format? If not, I might make one myself and stick it on GitHub, if you don't mind.

Comment: That's provided by http://vimscripts.org/: [here](https://github.com/vim-scripts/PatternComplete) and [the dependency](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ingo-library).